# por que no ejecuta el emulador de android estudio?

Tags: emulación

Ayer actualice la versión de Android Studio. Pero ahora no me permite ejecutar el emulador, y me sale el siguiente mensaje:

> error initializing ADB: Android debug Bridge not found

**¿Que puede estar pasando?**

Gracias a todos por sus prontas respuestas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede ser alguna de las siguientes cosas:

1) La versión de ADB que tienes no corresponde a la versión de Android Studio que instalaste.

2) Android studio no encuentra el ejecutable ADB.

¿Tienes las herramientas Android Sdk Platform Tools actualizadas? Puedes utilizar el SDK Manager para confirmarlo.

Comment: gracias, si aparece todo actualizado, creo que es que no encuentra el ADB, que puedo hacer en ese caso?

Comment: Depende de tu sistema operativo. En mi caso (Windows 10), adb se encuentra en C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools ¿puedes confirmar tu sistema operativo?
Si lo localizas, puedes probar agregándo esa ruta a la variable PATH del sistema operativo.

Comment: Siendo maquinas virtuales a mi me paso tambien, que se me actualizo firewall y ha bloqueado el acceso a las maquinas. Tube que volver abrir los puertos

Comment: gracias, si lo descargue nuevamente y lo puse en la ubicacion que me diste y funcionó. gracias